# How to split dictionary column in dataframe and make a new columns for each key values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe which has a column containing multiple values, separated by ",".

```
id data
0   {'1':A, '2':B, '3':C}
1   {'1':A}
2   {'0':0}
```

How can I split up the keys-values of 'data' column and make a new column for each key values present in it, without removing the original 'data' column.

desired output.

```
id data                   1   2   3   0
0   {'1':A, '2':B, '3':C} A   B   C   Nan
1   {'1':A}               A   Nan Nan Nan
2   {'0':0}               Nan Nan Nan 0

Thank you in advance :).
```

Comment: What's the result of `print(type(df['data'].iloc[0]))` ?

Comment: @richardec <class 'str'>

Comment: Are there really not any quotes around the values in the JSON objects? So it's really `'1':A,` not `'1':'A',` ?

Comment: @richardec yes the values are like {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0}

Comment: It's okay if digits like `0` are unquoted, but in your real data, are there any non-digits like letters unquoted?

Comment: Yes, mainly it has digits only, I only see few non-digits letters and that are unquoted as well.

Comment: Okay, check my answer now. I added some code to try to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a regular expression to convert the data into a format that can be parsed as JSON. Then, `pd.json_normalize` will do the job nicely:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'(["\'])\s*:(.+?)\s*(,?\s*["\'}])', '\\1:\'\\2\'\\3', regex=True)

import ast
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['data'])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                             data    1    2    3    0
0  {'1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C'}    A    B    C  NaN
1                      {'1': 'A'}    A  NaN  NaN  NaN
2                      {'0': '0'}  NaN  NaN  NaN    0
```